# How to specify the relative path to an image for background images in tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to integrate custom background images within my project.
I'm using tailwindCSS

My directory is structured like this:

```
-- assets
  |-- images
      |-- image1.svg
-- layouts
  |-- index.html 
-- tailwind.config.js
```

In my index.html i want to add image1.svg as background image.

How should i pass the relative path into `bg-[url('__path__')]`?

Comment: Does your build system handle `url()` for you or does it leave them as-is? Where is the Tailwind input CSS file?

Answer (score 0):

The directory structure you have provided looks like your source files. The relative url would be relative from where your css file is, to where the image is in your build or production files. This is because the Tailwind CSS build step does not change the url, as it is fairly dumb, so will not change the source files location with the final build location.

For the file structure you provide it would be `class="bg-[url('../assets/images/image1.svg')]"`. That assumes the Tailwind CSS output is included in the `index.html` file.

Note, it is often easier to use a root-relative url that begins with a forward slash (/) which is relative to the root directory of the website. So in your case it might end up something like `class="bg-[url('/images/image1.svg')]"`. Assuming that `images` is located in the root directory of your website. The advantage of this method is also that the css can be hosted in any location on the website as it is always relative to the root directory of the website.